# React Native Expo: Cannot add child that doesn't have a YogaNode - Error on Android

Tags: react-native

I am stuck with this error:

```
Cannot add a child that doesn't have a YogaNode to a parent without a measure function! 
(Trying to add a 'ReactRawTextShadowNode' to a 'LayoutShadowNode')
```

The app is on expo and works fine in iOS
but on Android I always get this error when pressing the button for authentication.

Earlier it was working fine, I tried to reset my commits to track the error but for no help.

I think, whenever this function is executed, the error arises:

```
onButtonPress = async () => {
  const { code } = this.props;
  await this.props.loginUser({ code });
  if (this.props.error) {
   await AsyncStorage.removeItem('code');
   this.props.navigation.goBack();
  } else {
    await AsyncStorage.setItem('code', code);
    await this.props.orderUpdate();
    await this.props.menuFetch();
    this.props.navigation.navigate('main');
  }
};
```

Note that the props are accessing redux state and calling redux actions.

Comment: There might be the problem in your render method, can you please post your render method code?

Answer (score 1):

This issue having a different reason:

- Might be the comments inside the render method of component so try to remove comments inside render method of component component.
- Might be  because of  that you have not closed a tag correctly
- Might be using of && operator inside render method so remove '&&'
  operator and use ternary operator.

Instead    `{ foobar && <View/> }`

Use this       `{ foobar ? <View/> : null }`